# Chain using lodash, tap() is executed first

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I'm trying to use lodash chain to execute actions synchronously, but it seems .tap() is executed first, and I couldn't figure out a proper way to do so using promise. I though chain in lodash allows actions to follow in a sync way, means tap will not execute until forEach ends

```js
const ids = [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "refs": [
          {
              "skuId": 693194,
              "sizeId": "12M",
              "colorId": "ROSE"
          },
          {
              "skuId": 693195,
              "sizeId": "14M",
              "colorId": "ROSE"
          },
          {
              "skuId": 973804,
              "sizeId": "6M",
              "colorId": "GREEN"
          }
        ]
       },
       {
        "id": 2,
        "refs": [
          {
              "skuId": 693174,
              "sizeId": "13M",
              "colorId": "RED"
          },
          {
              "skuId": 693995,
              "sizeId": "14M",
              "colorId": "BLUS"
          }
        ]
       } 
     ]
     
     let id = 1
     
     _(ids)
     .chain()
     .map(value => {
        id = _.result(_.find(value.refs, function(sku) {
                  return sku.colorId === 'ROSE' && 
                    sku.sizeId === '14M';
                                    }), 'skuId');
                                    
     })
     .tap(() => console.log('id: ', id))
     .value()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There's nothing async about this code? Why do you mention promises?

Comment: @nem035 what do you mean, I meant using promise instead of chain

Comment: I'm not sure what you question is. Are you saying `tap` is excecuted first and you want to know why? Or you want to refactor this code to use promises?

Comment: @SeanNewell either way I'm trying to find a way to refactor the code to use promise or find a better way to use lodash chain

Comment: Just don't use `forEach` and global variables. I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but `find` or `map` will be more appropriate.

Comment: you're assigning to `id` on each value and will be overridden

Comment: What makes you think that `tap` is executed first? What output do you get, and what do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you are using `chain` correctly - [check out the docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#chain), you have to unwrap the value with a call to `.value()` like in the documentation example. Tap is not actually executed first.

```
let id = null;

_.chain(ids)
  .forEach(value => {
    id = _.result(_.find(value.refs, function(sku) {
      return sku.colorId === 'ROSE'
        && sku.sizeId === '14M';
       }), 'skuId');                                      
  })
  .tap(() => console.log(id))
  .value();
```

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do, but I would rewrite it to use map to get rid of that outer id:

```js
const ids = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "refs": [
      {
          "skuId": 693194,
          "sizeId": "12M",
          "colorId": "ROSE"
      },
      {
          "skuId": 693195,
          "sizeId": "14M",
          "colorId": "ROSE"
      },
      {
          "skuId": 973804,
          "sizeId": "6M",
          "colorId": "GREEN"
      }
    ]
   },
   {
    "id": 2,
    "refs": [
      {
          "skuId": 693174,
          "sizeId": "13M",
          "colorId": "RED"
      },
      {
          "skuId": 693995,
          "sizeId": "14M",
          "colorId": "BLUS"
      }
    ]
   } 
 ]

let val = _.chain(ids)
  .map(value => {
    return _.result(
      _.find(
        value.refs,
        sku => sku.colorId === 'ROSE' && sku.sizeId === '14M'
      ),
      'skuId');
  })
  .value();

console.log(val);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

You still might need to tweak you code a little to get what you are expecting.

Comment: I updated my code, in fact I'm trying to assign Id because I'm doing more things with inside the tap

Comment: @kyserslick Update your question to fully explain what you are trying to do inside tap. It is likely what you are doing is wrong since the top level `id` is only the last id assigned to it. If you are trying to combine the ids, `reduce` is probably what you want.

Also, the reason you have `undefined` as an output is that the second item in your array has no match for a ref that has both color ROSE and size 14M.

Comment: @kyserslick I just updated my code to print out the resultant array, which has the matching skuIDs. The first item does have a match, the second item does not (hence it is undefined). After calling the function `value` lodash evaluates your chain (`chain` initiates a lazily evaluated expression), and returns a plain value (in this case an array).

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Indeed I'm more likely to use an array as a result since I'll need all the matching result. tkx

Answer (score 0):

If you add a line to dump the value of `id` inside `map`, you'll notice `id` was set twice and the 2nd time was `null` which override the value you wanted.

```js
const ids = [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "refs": [
          {
              "skuId": 693194,
              "sizeId": "12M",
              "colorId": "ROSE"
          },
          {
              "skuId": 693195,
              "sizeId": "14M",
              "colorId": "ROSE"
          },
          {
              "skuId": 973804,
              "sizeId": "6M",
              "colorId": "GREEN"
          }
        ]
       },
       {
        "id": 2,
        "refs": [
          {
              "skuId": 693174,
              "sizeId": "13M",
              "colorId": "RED"
          },
          {
              "skuId": 693995,
              "sizeId": "14M",
              "colorId": "BLUS"
          }
        ]
       } 
     ]
     
     let id = 1
     
     _(ids)
     .chain()
     .map(value => {
        id = _.result(_.find(value.refs, function(sku) {
                  return sku.colorId === 'ROSE' && 
                    sku.sizeId === '14M';
                                    }), 'skuId');
        // Add this line to inspect the id value in map
        console.log('id (in map): ', id);
     })
     .tap(() => console.log('id: ', id))
     .value()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```